# Aligning cell text in scrollable tbody

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to right align my text in the last column of the following table:

```
<table class="dataview">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th><span class="right">Balance</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 1</td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 2</td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$4000.00</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Using the following CSS:

```
.dataview{
  width: 830px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.dataview th, .dataview td{
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;  
}
.dataview th:nth-child(1), .dataview td:nth-child(1){min-width: 350px;}
.dataview th:nth-child(2), .dataview td:nth-child(2){min-width: 350px;}
.dataview th:nth-child(3), .dataview td:nth-child(3){min-width: 100px;}

.dataview thead{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;  
}
.dataview tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black
}
.dataview tbody tr:nth-last-child(1){
  border-bottom: none;
}
.dataview thead tr{
  display: block;
  position: relative;  
}
.dataview tbody{
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;  
}
.dataview td.right{
  text-align:right;
  background-color: green;
}
.dataview tbody tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color: powderblue;
}
```

The text in the last column does align right; however, if there is a scrollbar present, part of the text is under the scroll bar.  I have attempted padding, margins, surrounding the text in a span or div and I cannot get the text out from under the scrollbar. How do I fix this so the text aligns correctly?  [CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/ElCid91/pen/vYEdXPm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin` and `padding` wont work in your case as the table has a fixed width of 830px. These properties will be hidden.

If the table's width doesn't need to be fixed, you may refer to `#table-2` example.

```css
body{
  background-color: tomato;
}
.dataview{
  width: 830px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dataview th, .dataview td{
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;  
}
.dataview th:nth-child(1), .dataview td:nth-child(1){min-width: 350px;}
.dataview th:nth-child(2), .dataview td:nth-child(2){min-width: 350px;}
.dataview th:nth-child(3), .dataview td:nth-child(3){min-width: 100px;}

.dataview thead{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;  
}
.dataview tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black
}
.dataview tbody tr:nth-last-child(1){
  border-bottom: none;
}
.dataview thead tr{
  display: block;
  position: relative;  
}
.dataview tbody{
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height:40px;  
}
.dataview th.right, .dataview td.right{
  text-align:right;    
}
.dataview tbody tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color: powderblue;
}

#table-2 {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 830px;
}
#table-2.dataview th:nth-child(3),  #table-2.dataview td:nth-child(3){padding-right: 20px}


#table-3 tbody {
  height: auto;
}

#table-3 {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 830px;
}
#table-3.dataview th:nth-child(3),  #table-3.dataview td:nth-child(3){
  //padding-right: 20px
}
```

```html
<table class="dataview">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>      
      <th class="right">Balance</th>      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 1</td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>      
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 2</td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$4000.00</td>      
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>


<table class="dataview" id="table-2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>      
      <th class="right">Balance</th>      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 1</td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>      
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 2</td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$4000.00</td>      
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="dataview" id="table-3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>      
      <th class="right">Balance</th>      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 1</td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>      
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 2</td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$4000.00</td>      
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: joohong89, this answer works; however, if I make the tbody height so that the scroll bar goes away, there is a huge gap at the right side of the table.  is there a way to push the text left when the scroll bar appears?

Comment: @Elcid_91 if u remove fixed height, as seen in `#table-3`, u can remove padding to remove spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `min-width:100px` to `width:100%` on your 3rd column's styles.

```
.dataview th:nth-child(3), .dataview td:nth-child(3){width:100%;}
```

Then it will collapse and expand as needed outside of the scroll bar.

```css
.dataview{
  width: 830px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.dataview th, .dataview td{
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;  
}
.dataview th:nth-child(1), .dataview td:nth-child(1){min-width: 350px;}
.dataview th:nth-child(2), .dataview td:nth-child(2){min-width: 350px;}
.dataview th:nth-child(3), .dataview td:nth-child(3){width:100%;}

.dataview thead{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;  
}
.dataview tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black
}
.dataview tbody tr:nth-last-child(1){
  border-bottom: none;
}
.dataview thead tr{
  display: block;
  position: relative;  
}
.dataview tbody{
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;  
}
.dataview td.right{
  text-align:right;
  background-color: green;
}
.dataview tbody tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<table class="dataview">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th><span class="right">Balance</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 1</td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td>Customer 2</td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$4000.00</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try and add in the class !important attribute:

```
.dataview td.right{
  text-align:right !important;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code here https://jsfiddle.net/n8jx40tz/ and it works fine, or maybe I miss understood your question.

Comment: The alignment is not the the issue, it's the overlap of the table cell with the scroll-bar.

Comment: you can try the following body {overflow-x: hidden;}